# AttributeError: '_EnumDict' object has no attribute '_cls_name'

Tags: django

I have been receiving this error in several python based projects including my current one Shuup and i'm not sure how to resolve it. I have research other errors but none speak about this one. Any help to steer me in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: This is the github repository: https://github.com/bastianhilton/Shuup-Fork

Answer (score 2):

It is a issue on django-enumfields that occurs on Python 3.9.2+, according to [this](https://github.com/hzdg/django-enumfields/commit/8a54ab6ca1a406b4f736b1d8a1daff49431a1c5c).

You can update this lib to a new version, but there is a risk of incompatibility (shuup 3.1 requires `"django-enumfields>=2.0.0,<2.1"`).

Try this:
`pip install django-enumfields==2.1.1`